# Definition of congruence

Tags: terminology, definition

In the book *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*, 8th edition, by Kenneth Rosen, the following definition of **congruence** is provided:

> If *a* and *b* are integers and *m* is a positive integer, then *a* is
> congruent to *b modulo m* if *m* divides *a − b*.

My question is why is there an "if" in the definition and not an "iff".

Comment: Because it is costumary in mathematical English to use "if" as a synonym of "if and only if" when it's in a definition *and* in that particular phrasing (for instance, the first "if" is just the usual "if" that you would find whan a hypothesis is introduced).

Comment: The use of "if and only if" (and the, imho ugly and easy to confuse or miss, abbreviation "iff") in definitions is not universal. For many, the fact that it's a definition implies that it is an "if and only if", in that the name will only be used if the conditions are met (and so, the "only" provides the other clause). If it is labeled as a definition, you may read it as an if and only if even if only "if" is stated; this is a matter of well-understood convention.